# Android Fullscreen with Vue Capacitor

Tags: android, vue.js, fullscreen, capacitor

I'm playing around with a multi-system app via Vue+Capacitor. One of the things I'd like to have is a button that makes my app go into Fullscreen, especially on Android. Pretty sure I'm gonna need those CapacitorPlugins, but since I'm an Android noob I'm not sure what I have to do to get it to work

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        registerPlugin(EchoPlugin.class);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    private void hideSystemBars() {
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController =
                ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(getWindow().getDecorView());
        if (windowInsetsController == null) {
            return;
        }
        // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
        windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(
                WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        );
        // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
        windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
    }
}
```

Please note that the function hideSystemBars works fine and does exactly what I want if I call it in the MainActivity.onCreate for example.

MyPlugin.java:

```
@CapacitorPlugin(name = "MyPlugin")
public class MyPlugin extends Plugin {

    @PluginMethod()
    public void fullScreen(PluginCall call) {
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController =
                ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(getWindow().getDecorView());
        if (windowInsetsController == null) {
            return;
        }
        // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
        windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(
                WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        );
        // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
        windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
    }
}
```

The problem here is that this plugin can't use getWindow(), I guess due to permission stuff. Do I need to pass something to the plugin? Or do I call MainActivity.hideSystemBars from the plugin and how would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way but after trying some stuff I at least found one way that works. So in case anyone has something similar...
Basically, the plugin is allowed to run stuff on MainActivity's UiThread, so the following works:

MainActivity (does nothing special but register the plugin):

```
public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        registerPlugin(MyPlugin.class);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}
```

Plugin:

```
@CapacitorPlugin(name = "Androidfuncs")
public class MyPlugin extends Plugin {

    @PluginMethod()
    public void fullscreen(PluginCall call) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController =
                        ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView());
                if (windowInsetsController == null) {
                    return;
                }
                // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
                windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(
                        WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
                );
                // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
                windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            }
        });
    }
}
```